# Cómo escapar el símbolo de porcentaje % en el printf

Tags: c, printf

¿Cómo puedo imprimir un carácter `%` usando la función `printf()`?

He intentado esto:

```
printf("\%prueba\n");
```

Pero no funciona.

Comment: Prueba `%%` en lugar de `\%`.

Answer (score 9):

`\%` no es una secuencia legal de caracteres especiales por lo que es probable que el compilador convierta `\%` en un único carácter `%` , entonces la función estaría recibiendo solo `prinft("%")`

Siempre que `printf` vea un carácter `%` en su cadena, siempre mirará los siguientes caracteres para decidir qué hacer. Pero no hay un siguiente carácter como *(d , f , c , s)* por ejemplo por lo que `printf` está confundido.

Entonces en el contexto de cadenas de formato interpretadas por `printf`  , la **`regla`** es que si quieres imprimir un solo `%` , deberás escribir  dos veces el carácter . `%%`   *Ojo que solo funcionará para la función `printf`*  [Fuente](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/cescapes.html)

```
int main(void) {
  printf("%%prueba");
  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://repl.it/repls/RelevantEmbellishedWaterfall)</kbd>

Hay dos formas más, al menos para imprimir también un `%` , pasando un formato a la función `printf` , ya sea `%c` *(caracter ASCII)* o `%s` *(cadena de caracteres)*

```
printf("%c \n", '%');
printf("%s", "%");
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://repl.it/repls/LuminousSuddenForce)</kbd>

Comment: @JackNavaRow Perfecto , añadí alguna "explicación" para mejorar un poco la comprensión , Saludos

Comment: Es comun tambien en otro lengujes de programacion se deban hacer lo mismo ya que muchos se basan en C

Comment: Agrega la forma larga: `printf("%c", '%');`, no lo sé, se ve bonita tambien :P

Comment: @NaCl recién entre , así que está agregado , además con `%s` también :)