# Secuencia de escape ambigua en C

Tags: c, linux, ensamblador, printf

Desde un archivo.c estoy escribiendo un archivo destino a.asm (código ensamblador). En una de las lineas de dicho archivo ensamblador debe decir lo siguiente:

```
addb $48, %dl
```

Para ello (en condiciones ideales) yo debería usar en el archivo.c la siguiente linea:

```
fprintf(writefile, "\t\taddb $48, %dl \n");
```

Pero despues de compilar el archivo.c y posteriormente el archivo de destino a.asm (ahorro detalles porque no es esa la cuestión) el resultado que aparece en a.asm es el siguiente:

```
addb $48, -725569003l
```

En resumen:

tengo el problema que en **el `fprintf` del archivo.c toma el "`%dl`" como si fuera un campo "`%d`"** y una "l" adjunta, al que hay que ingresar una variable conteniendo un valor decimal .

No domino esto de las secuencias de escape, así que necesito vuestra ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Trauma, ha sido rápido y fácil.  Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Vale, a ver si me entero como va esto.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo escapar el símbolo de porcentaje % en el printf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154042/c%c3%b3mo-escapar-el-s%c3%admbolo-de-porcentaje-en-el-printf)

Answer (score 2):

Como la línea

`fprintf(writefile, "\t\taddb $48, %dl \n");`

va a dar problemas porque printf (o fprintf) utiliza el símbolo "%d" para incluir un valor decimal dentro de la cadena de caracteres a imprimir.

Lo que se debe hacer es añadir a `"%d"` el símbolo `%` delante, quedando así:

`fprintf(writefile, "\t\taddb $48, %%dl \n");`

Y ya no tendremos problemas.